# How to know which AHCI driver Windows 7 is using?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, ahci

I have AHCI enabled in Windows 7 through `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Msahci`.

My Asus motherboard comes with a drivers software including AHCI drivers. I used their setup program and I assume it installed the AHCI driver.

I did a search in the whole Windows folder and don't see a file with ahci in the same other than `msahci.sys`

How do I know which ahci driver Windows is using and how do I switch to the Asus one instead of the one from Microsoft? Is Device manager used?

Answer (score 2):

Go to your device manager (Right-click Computer, Manage, then Device Manager) and under IDE ATA/ATAPI-Controllers, right click one of the entries and then click the driver tab. This will show you what drivers are being used.

Comment: I don't see it in any of the entries. Does it get loaded only when the BIOS is set to AHCI even if its enabled in the registry?